# Changing shape of textview in Android framework

Tags: android, textview

I am working on android frameworks. I need to modify the shape of the textview such that it should have rounded corners. Can you please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XML file saved at res/drawable/gradient_box.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FFFF0000"
        android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
        android:angle="45"/>
    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

This layout XML applies the shape drawable to a View:

```
<TextView
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_box"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

This application code gets the shape drawable and applies it to a View:
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable shape = res. getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_box);

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewByID(R.id.textview);
tv.setBackground(shape);
```

**Copy&Paste from [http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html8TQ&sig2=cJxPZWmjJNdYLl7Bi29vdA), first result when you google "android textView rounded corners"**

**[EDIT]**

As you want to change the source of the android framework, you can alter the style of the TextView by altering the default Drawables. In the sources the various Drawables are grouped in an inner class called Drawables:

```
class Drawables {
        final Rect mCompoundRect = new Rect();
        Drawable mDrawableTop, mDrawableBottom, mDrawableLeft, mDrawableRight;
        int mDrawableSizeTop, mDrawableSizeBottom, mDrawableSizeLeft, mDrawableSizeRight;
        int mDrawableWidthTop, mDrawableWidthBottom, mDrawableHeightLeft, mDrawableHeightRight;
        int mDrawablePadding;
    }
```

Just alter these Drawables as you like and you have redefined TextView.

I'm referring to that version of the [TextView sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java).

Comment: the answer you have insisted is valid for application level only but not in framework.Actually i want to change the open source code of android such that the shape of textview changes that means whenever we are accessing textview in application level then textview with my specified shape should be displayed